# calling python script from another python script, asynchronously

Tags: python

I have a python cgi script, wherein after user enters the details in a form, it is sent to python script for processing and returns throwing a message in the browser. Before throwing a message to the browser, i want to call a python script which runs in the background and sends out mail once its task is completed. Any idea how to call a python script from another python script in the background?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2496772/asynchronous-background-processes-in-python

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) module for that, or use a task queue like [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2496772/asynchronous-background-processes-in-python) on how to use the `subprocess` modul for async calls.

Comment: If a question is a dup, close it as a dup, don't write an answer linking to the dup.